# setcookie(); does not set cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have following problem, I am trying to set cookies without any success. `setcookie();` function returns true so it looks like it setting cookie however when I am trying to access it on the same or following page I get error 'Undefined Index....'

```
<?
session_start();
ob_start();


echo setcookie("order",$_SESSION['cart'],time()+3600,'/',NULL);



//added to see if Cookie is set
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($_COOKIE);
exit();




if($_GET['paypal'] == 1){
    header("Location: /paypal-express-checkout/process.php");
}else{
    header("Location: /insert_order.php");
}
ob_end_flush();
exit();
?>
```

next page follows like this

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../includes/inc_config.php");
include_once("../order.php");
include_once("config.php");
include_once("paypal.class.php");

#region POST
if(!isset($_GET['token'])) //Post Data received from product list page.
{
    //Mainly we need 4 variables from an item, Item Name, Item Price, Item Number and Item Quantity.

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['order'])){
        exit();
    }
    $paypal_data = '';
    $ItemTotalPrice = 0;
    $order = unserialize($_COOKIE['order']);
    print_r($order);
    exit;
```

Comment: Cookies are only "visible" in ```$_COOKIE``` on the next page load.

Comment: **Common Pitfalls:** `Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.`

Comment: As per my original post the cookie is not visible on the following page( next loaded page )

Comment: So what does `$_SESSION['cart']` contain at the time you are trying to use it as cookie value? I see you are trying to use `unserialize` on the cookie value in your second script, so it must be something already serialized? Btw., you should not use `unserialize` on parameters coming in from the outside, it can have security implications (can f.e. be used to create an instance of any class defined in the current script). And if you have a session, then why are you trying to pass a complex data structure via cookie anyway – instead of having it in the session in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks and yes the data passed is serialized data however the problem is that it is not set(cookie is not set) for the second script to read it. The security flaw is not an issue due to the site being a fast prototype. I am just puzzled why it does not set the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the domain value to NULL. Try leaving the NULL away:

`echo setcookie("order",$_SESSION['cart'],time()+3600,'/');`

OR set it to your domain:

`echo setcookie("order",$_SESSION['cart'],time()+3600,'/',".yourdomain.com");`

Comment: I have tried every single combination of this and it just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would var_dump or print_r the $_COOKIE variable before I make a decision that it's not getting passed through. Holding that thought once you setcookie something gets registered into the $_COOKIE variable for sure.

I agree with the statements above since you only can access $_COOKIE on the next refresh but there is another way to do it to make your form or page more interactive.

I would register the cookie and use a php page refresh (display a working... div while thats happening) then come back to the page and try to do what you originally tried doing. Very basic but pretty much straight forward.

Comment: Hi, this solution does not work, after setting meta tag to refresh the variable still isn't in COOKIES.

Comment: Try to post to the page to the web server to process the data; refresh isn't a strong case. You need to figure out a mechanism to do that.